# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at fsck boot after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, gnome, graphics, fsck

### Overall gist,

I recently installed Nvidia drivers for GTX 1050 Ti Mobile for the first time. After installation, I restarted the laptop and "boom..", It's forever stuck with the "fsck" screen. [This is how it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsLNp.jpg). I'm a complete noob with Nvidia driver but have been enjoying using ubuntu but I'm no pro in that either. So it would be amazing if you guys can help me out!

### System Configuration,

- **LAPTOP :** XPS 9570
- DUAL BOOT WITH **WINDOWS 10** and **UBUNTU 18.04.4 LTS**
- **GRAPHICS :** INTEL and GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile

### Detailed flow of "What I did, before rebooting",

- I first checked out the devices in the system using `lshw -c display`, which returned two graphic cards with **Nvidia unclaimed** [Sure about this] and **INTEL claimed with configuration i915** [I'm not sure about this].
- After which, I ran `ubuntu-drivers devices`, To check the recommended Nvidia driver,
- Then ran, `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to install the driver.
- The system asked to remove certain packages, in order to install the driver.
- I used `sudo apt autoremove`, [These are the packages, that it removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgVIz.jpg), Sorry about the image clarity.
- Then again ran,`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, and nvidia drivers were installed, In my case, it was **nvidia-driver-460-server**.
- Choose to nvidia mode, using `prime-select nvidia` and restarted the system.

### After restarting

- The boot stucks with fsck checks, It does provide an option of stopping the check, that is

  `fsckd-cancel-msg:Press Ctrl+C to cancel all filesystem checks in progress`

  but doesn't seem to be useful in my case.

### Things that I tried,

- Tried rebooting with secure mode disabled.
- Used recovery mode, to uninstall the nvidia packages, using `sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'` and then rebooted, still it remains the same with fsck checks stuck during the boot.
- Tried setting up intel graphics back, using `prime-select intel`, Still stuck in the same error.
- Checking the graphics devices now shows that both intel and nvidia is **"UNCLAIMED"**.

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ed000000-ed07ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

- Able to access ubuntu by using `nomodeset` option in grub but the ubuntu display is very low.

Sorry if the information isn't enough, Let me know if you need more details. It would be helpful if you can provide a solution or suggestion to fix this issue.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI and try again. No further reinstallation of drivers should be needed.

Comment: I tried that @ChanganAuto, The boot stuck still persists.

Comment: Have you installed in UEFI mode and in a GPT drive? Theoretically not a requirement but  in practice it is. Also update the firmware (UEFI).